# How to send received file to external api with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I have a laravel api that receive a file and I have to save and send this file to another (external) api.

I can save the file to storage, but I can not send the file to the external api.

My upload method is this:

```php
public function upload(Request $request) {
        if ($request->hasFile('image')
            && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
            $name = $request->userid;
            $extension = $request->image->extension();
            $nameFile = "prefix_{$name}.{$extension}";
            $file = $request->image;
            $file->storeAs('users', $nameFile);

            $this->sendFile('./storage/users/' . $nameFile, $request->sellerid, 'type');

            $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/storage/users/' . $nameFile;
            return $url;
        }
    }
```

And this works, but the *sendDocument* function don't:

```php
private function sendFile($file, $sellerid, $type) 
    {
        $auth = 'XXXX';
        
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.url.com/",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{$file}\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n{$type}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Basic {$auth}",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: multipart/form-data;",
        ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            throw "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    }
```

How I send the file to a external api?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem using Guzzle:

```php
private function sendFile($file, $sellerid, $type) 
    {
        $url = "api";

        $auth = 'XXXX';

        $client = new Client();
        
        $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'category',
                    'contents' => $type
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'file',
                    'contents' => fopen($file, 'r'),
                    'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']
                ],
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => "Basic {$auth}"
            ],
        ]);
        return $response->getBody();
    }
```

Comment: i tires with last one day, i did mistake at header parsing. i passed 
'accept' => 'application/json', and 
'content-type' => 'application/json',
So im getting error. now fixed. 
Thanks Harry

Answer (score -1):

To get this to work with just CURL, use CURLFile first and pass the result in with your post params:

```
<?php
    
    // Create a cURL handle
    $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/upload.php');
    
    // Create a CURLFile object
    $cfile = new CURLFile('cats.jpg','image/jpeg','test_name');
    
    // Assign POST data
    $data = array('test_file' => $cfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    
    // Execute the handle
    curl_exec($ch);
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php